# fetch data from controller view using slim

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I would like to know how to retrieve a value from a view in the controller using php slim

In this method I need to retrieve the selected product id

```
public function getProdutosDevolucao($request, $response, $args) {
    
    $idProduto= $request->getParam('data-id');// tentei fazer assim não da certo;
}
```

[image]

The data comes from a method that populates the view in this foreach:

```
<div class="col-md-12 lista-itens2" id="lista-devolucoes">
{% for devolucao in produtos_devolucao %}
    <div class="media item" href="javascript:;" data-tipo="{{ devolucao.produto_tipo | trim }}" 
        onclick="setItem2($(this))" 
        data-id="{{ devolucao.produto_id }}"
        data-embalagem="{{ devolucao.embalagem }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I thank anyone who can help me in any way, because I'm a beginner and I don't have much experience

Answer (score 0):

Any `data-` attribute value won't be passed to server by default html. You need to create a html form, add there input and put value from your `data-id` to input `value` attribute.

`<input name='data-id'  value='10'>`